# how to use “fribidi_log2vis” function on localhost

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have to use `fribidi_log2vis` in PHP. When I call it, my localhost (XAMPP) shows this error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function fribidi_log2vis()`

but this function is exists in php.net (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fribidi-log2vis.php)

Comment: `(PHP 4 >= 4.0.4 and PHP 4 <= 4.1.0, PECL fribidi >= 1.0)`. This is crucial.

Answer (score 2):

Fribidi is a PECL extension that is not bundled with PHP by default. Installing instructions: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php